# Bazel workaround for filenames with ':' in them?

Tags: bazel

I have Python tests that depend on files with ':' in the filenames.

I would like to put the tests under bazel, but bazel becomes unhappy when I supply the files in the data argument to py_test, complaining that:

```
invalid target name 'bazel_test_cases/foo/input/foo:bar': target names may not contain ':'
```

Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a workaround. `:` is normally used to separate the package and the target name. And trying to escape with `\` fails with *target names may not contain '\'*